# What "theme" does Stack Overflow use for its code formatting?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I love the simplicity of the color theme that Stack Overflow uses for its code formatting. Is this an established theme or is it built custom?

Can anyone point me to a location of the color mappings etc., used, so I can incorporate the same in my IDEs?

Comment: See also [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work). Personally, I think [the theme that GitHub uses](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown) looks ***much*** better: [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist). But really, if you want to check out an awesome syntax theme, check out [base16's dark theme](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-textmate).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Stackoverflow uses [Google Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) for highlighting the code snippets.

Comment: I wonder where the future for Google Prettify lies giving the future closing of Google code.